# Adding a repeater to a MS-Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I haven't worked in Access in quite some time.  But, I have a report that has a main query, with grouping.  The report is based on a database like this:

Each office has many divisions.
Each Division has many projects

So, I group by office.  But, each division has a lot of other relationships I would like to include in the report.  Like Staff members.  Is there a way to create a secondary, and more, query and loop through that to add data to the report?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with both forms and reports.  You need the [SubForm control](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA).  This allows you embed one form/report within another.  You can also define which fields to join on.  This allows the main/outer report to filter the sub/inner report.

The link above contains detailed instructions taken from the Office website.

Comment: In addition to what 'destination-data' gave you, please see this link.

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Just play around with it for a while.  You can definitely do what you described.  You probably just need to spend a little time on it.

Comment: Thanks!  This was helpful!